# Sphinx shows local python path with type hinting

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-typing

I'm automatically generating docs using Sphinx using `sphinx-quickstart` in html format. The result seems to incorrectly parse type hinting of json.

Let's say I have the following Python function with type hinting:

```
import json
def some_function(param1: str, param2: json) -> list:
    pass
```

This function generates the following html output:

```
 some_function(param1: str, param2: <module 'json' from 'path_to_conda/miniconda3/envs/ienw/lib/json/__init__.py'>) → list
```

We now see type hinting of param2 being quite odd and I would not expect to have my local Python path in the documentation.

Some details on `conf.py` (it mostly follows the default conf from `sphinx-quickstart`):

```
extensions = [
    "rinoh.frontend.sphinx",
    "sphinx.ext.autosummary",
]
html_theme = "alabaster"
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how we can hide my local path from the documentation?

Comment: What kind of *type* is `json`—the `json` *module*— in the first place…?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this

```
import json
def some_function(param1: str, param2: json) -> list:
    pass
```

does violate [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) which says

> Type hints may be built-in classes (including those defined in
> standard library or third-party extension modules), abstract base
> classes, types available in the types module, and user-defined classes
> (including those defined in the standard library or third-party
> modules).

as `json` after `import json` is not `class` which might be proved as follows:

```
import inspect
import json
print(inspect.isclass(json))  # False
```

You might elect to use [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) instead as you might then use Annotation to convey information what is expected to user, simple example is:

```
def speed(distance: "meters", duration: "seconds") -> "m/s":
    return distance/duration
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hint that a parameter should be a JSON-string, then don't use the *`json` module* as a hint, just because it's named "`json`". You're not going to pass *the `json` module* as argument into the function, so the type checking is useless anyway.

JSON is a string with a specific format. As such, the type hint must be a `str`, but you can express the required logic using a [type alias](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases) or [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype):

```
from typing import NewType

JSON = str
# or:
JSON = NewType('JSON', str)

def some_function(param1: str, param2: JSON) -> list:
    ...
```

Comment: In addition to the mentioned type, you could also use for instance `JsonDict = Dict[str, Any]` as mentioned here: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/182

Comment: That's not *JSON* then, that's just a dict…